# Reusing models in Web Api

Tags: c#, oop

I have a c# class as below

```
public class CreateStudent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I need another class with following properties

```
public class EditStudent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
}
```

I have repeated properties except that one field **(Date_of_Birth)** is added in the **EditStudent** Model.
Is there an option to reuse some of the properties from previous **CreateStudent** model

I am going to handle these data as Json objects in my front end **angularjs** based application

Comment: You should take a look at *inheritance* - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a null-able property.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
}
```

This way you only have one Student model that can accommodate both use-cases.

Answer (score 3):

you should be using inheritance feature here.

```
public class CreateStudent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
} 
public class EditStudent : CreateStudent
{
    public DateTime Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
}
```

[image]